# Two ee.Algirthms.If() in row: first shows correct result, second gives both cases

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

following case: I have an ui.Select widget with two items. Both items represent an area: 'AreaL' and 'AreaO'. lor and obk are tables with the polygons of both areas. NDVIGS1923 and NDVI1923OBK are imported ImageCollection from the Asset.

With ee.Algorithms.If() I try to check the item of the Ui.Select-Widget. As I understood I can just ceck one item in one If()-Function. There is a true-case and a false-case, Depending on if the statement is true or false.
It works well for the first ee.Algorithms.If(). But the seccond one doesn't work as expected. I tested it with these both print()-functions. Both, the true-case and the false-case are printed in the console. Regardless of whether I choose one item or the other.

1. Could someone explain to me why this is happening?
2. Is there another option I could provide to chose an ImageCollection from my Asset in my App as a User, using JavaScript in the GEE?

```
//Widget 
var areas = {
'AreaL': lor,
'AreaO': obk,
}; 

//Add DropDownList to the controlPanel of the app
var controlPanel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Select({
    items: Object.keys(areas),
    placeholder: "Wähle eine Option",
    value: null,
    onChange: LoadGrowingSeason}),
    ui.Checkbox({
   ...


// Check option of DDL and save right ImageCollection in var ndvigs
function LoadGrowingSeason(selection){
  ndvigs = ee.Algorithms.If({
    condition: ee.String(selection).equals('AreaL'),
    trueCase: NDVIGS1923,
    falseCase: NDVI1923OBK
  }); 

  ee.Algorithms.If({
    condition: ee.String(selection).equals('AreaO'),
    trueCase: print('Test'),
    falseCase: print('false')
  }); 
 print(ndvigs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the result of [client vs. server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) behavior, so it might be worth reading up on that if it's unfamiliar.

#### Why It's Happening

`ee.Algorithms.If` creates a server-side object by sending the condition and *both* cases to the server, and letting the server decide which to return. Before sending that to the server, your browser has to run all of that code client-side so that it knows what to send to the server.

Your first check works as expected because the client simply identifies the image collections, asks the server which to store in `ndvigs`, and *then* prints the correct case identified by the server.

For your second check, evauluating the `trueCase` and `falseCase` causes both `print` functions to be called immediately, and the `undefined` value returned by those functions is sent to the server.

#### How to Fix It

`ee.Algorithms.If` is only required for server-side objects. The selected values from a `ui.Select` are just client-side strings, so they can be checked with a regular `if/else`. Here's an updated version of your on-change callback using client-side conditionals:

```js
// Check option of DDL and save right ImageCollection in var ndvigs
function LoadGrowingSeason(selection){
  if (selection === "AreaL") {
    ndvigs = NDVIGS1923;
  }
  else {
    ndvigs = NDVI1923OBK;
  }
  
  if (selection === "AreaO") {
    print("Test")
  }
  else {
    print("false")
  }
  
  print(ndvigs);
}
```

That code could probably be cleaned up, but it should do what you're intending, and it will be faster because there is no need to wait for results from the server.